# How do I create a desktop shortcut for Eclipse in my Mint Cinnamon environment?

Tags: cinnamon, mint

So I have just installed Eclipse but it doesn't automatically create a desktop icon like Intellij Community Edition does. I am running Mint 17.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find Eclipse in the Menu and right-click on it. You will see "Add to desktop" option. Click on it. Done.

[image]

Or you could simply execute:

```
ln -s /your/eclipse/path/ ~/Desktop
```

which is in your case should be

```
ln -s /home/peter/Programs/eclipse/eclipse/eclipse ~/Desktop
```

And yet [here](http://xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html) is another way to create a Mint Cinnamon desktop application launcher as well as launchers for other Linux GUI.

Comment: Problem was that I could not find it on the menu

Comment: @Laser: well... you did not mention it in your question. Anyway, I added to the answer what I would do in such cases.

Comment: ln does not work. It won't start if you try and do that

Comment: @Laser: I tried, and it works like charm for me.

Comment: If you say so. I know what you want and I'll let you have it

Comment: @Laser: likewise...

Answer (score 4):

I could not find Eclipse on the "start" menu so I added a `/home/user/eclipse.desktop` file in my desktop which now looks like this

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Java IDE
Comment=Java IDE
Exec=/home/user/Programs/eclipse/eclipse/eclipse --started-from-file %U
TryExec=/home/user/pathtoeclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/user/pathtoeclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;
MimeType=
X-KDE-Protocols=;
```

And now it works